# Add an iframe to a tab and post to it

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, extjs

I try to add an iframe to a tab and post some data to it. I want to post, because I know about GET-parameter limitations, whereas in my case the data may be of arbitrary size. I do it like so:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe"),
tabpanel = Ext.getCmp("testTabPanel"),
tab,
form;
iframe.setAttribute("id", "testframe");
iframe.setAttribute("src", "page.php");
tab = tabpanel.add({
   title: "Test",
   contentEl:iframe
});
tabpanel.setActiveTab(tab);
form = Ext.getBody().createChild({
    tag: "form",
    cls: "x-hidden",
    id: "form",
    action: "page.php",
    target: "testframe",
    method: "POST"
});
form.createChild({
    tag:"input",
    type:"text",
    cls:"x-hidden",
    name:"data",
    value:"somedata"
});
form.dom.submit();
```

But it does not work. In `page.php` I check it with

```
print_r($_POST);
```

And it prints out empty Array.

Comment: so close: `iframe.setAttribute("name", "testframe");`

Comment: Hmm, it does not work. Still see the same picture in Chrome and Firefox. Just an empty `Array( );`

Comment: Oh, sorry! It works! Thank you, dandavis!